# Casting SQL Date Value using Convert.ToDateTime in C# is failing

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, datetime-conversion

To start, the error I'm getting is as follows:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

What I've done is returned a set of data from a SQL database into a datatable, from there I'm running an `if` statement on the c# code side to determine if one date is greater than the other. This has worked on numerous deployments, however a specific deployment on a new server is resulting in the above error.

Here is my code:

```
if
(
    Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartDate"].ToString()).Date >
    Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OriginalStartDate"].ToString()).Date
)
{
   ... do stuff ...
}
```

My understanding is that the data inside the column, converted to a string, is failing when trying to execute the `Convert.ToDateTime()`

The perplexing issue however is that this code has worked on other servers and this issue is isolated. So I get that it could be unique to the server however I don't know where to look.

Changing any regional settings, etc., is unfortunately not an option so I'm trying to find a way around this!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the format of the dates in the database? It's likely that the dates are recorded in one format, and your conversion is running in another.

Comment: What is the *type* in the database? It should be a DateTime, which means you shouldn't convert to a string and back at all. Just use `if ((DateTime) ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartDate"] > (DateTime) ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OriginalStartDate"]))`

Comment: Double checking the `type` both fields are of type DateTime. @JonSkeet I'll try your suggestion out accordingly. As for the format it looks like `2015-07-01 00:00:00.000` @MPelletier

Comment: Can you post some data from the database so we can see what's the format?

Comment: @JonSkeet your answer sorted it out for me! Thanks!

Comment: Okay, will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't be converting the values to strings and back in the first place. Wherever possible, avoid string conversions unless that's an essential part of what you're trying to do. In your case, you're really interested in `DateTime` values. They're `DateTime` in the database, and you want them as `DateTime` values in your code, so why introduce strings?

You should be able to use:

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
DateTime startDate = (DateTime) row["StartDate"];
DateTime originalStartDate = (DateTime) row["OriginalStartDate"];
if (startDate.Date > originalStartDate.Date)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. 100% correct here. I realised at the base I was trying to cut some corners which just caused me the headache, and of course the string conversion was unnecessary. Thanks for your insight. Appreciated.

Comment: If your data allow nulls, then I'd go with `DateTime? ColumnName = ((DateTime?)(dr["ColumnName"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["ColumnName"]));`  Even if nulls are not allowed, running this logic is still safe, should you later decide to alter the Schema to allow nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this?

```
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartDate"].ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")).Date > Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OriginalStartDate"].ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")).Date) 
        {
                ...do stuff...
        }
```